# what should I do with the n upgrade node permission in fedora 32

Tags: node.js, linux, permissions

I am using this command to upgrade the node version in fedora 32:

```
npm install -g n
n stable
```

when I using the `n stable` command, shows error like this:

```
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/corepack': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/npm': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/npx': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/common.gypi': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/config.gypi': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/node.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/node_api.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/js_native_api.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/js_native_api_types.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/node_api_types.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/node_buffer.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/node_object_wrap.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/node_version.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/v8config.h': Permission denied
cp: cannot remove '/usr/local/include/node/v8-internal.h': Permission denied
```

I did not want to using root user to upgrade the node, what should I do? Just change the `/usr/local` folder permission to current user? does this way had any side effect? I am not sure, what is the best way to  make the `n stable` command work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [installation section](https://github.com/tj/n#installation) in the documentation of `n` has instructions to avoid using `sudo` or working as an admin.

Quoting from the current version:

> To avoid requiring `sudo` for `n` and `npm` global installs, it is
> suggested you either install to your home directory using `N_PREFIX`,
> or take ownership of the system directories:
>
> ```
> # make cache folder (if missing) and take ownership
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/n
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/n
> # make sure the required folders exist (safe to execute even if they already exist)
> sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/share
> # take ownership of Node.js install destination folders
> sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/share
> ```